# I'd like to create a JSON object out of an HTML table. I'd like the end product to be used to tally input from multiple users

Tags: javascript, json

Active learner here, trying to figure out how to create a JSON object out of HTML table. I only want the value of one specific TD and want to give each value an incrementing number as a key. I'd like an output like below. My table has a TD for the city names, but it does not have one with a incrementing numerical value so I'd need to add that another way.

```
{
  "mycities" : [
    {
      "Seattle" : "1",
      "Chicago" : "2",
      "New York" : "3"
      "Pitt" : "4",
      "LA" : "5",
      "Fresno" : "6"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here is what my table looks like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>city name</th>
            <th>other city info</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Seattle</td>
            <td>Lots of rain</td>
        </tr>
        etc,etc,etc
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried using a replacer function but haven't got it figured out after much googling. Any help is appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("body").on("click",".submitButtonPri",function(){ 
        count= 1;
        function replacer(key, value) {
          if (typeof value === 'string') {
            return count;
          }
          return value;
        }

        var myRows = [];
        var $headers = $(".rightDash > table thead th");

        var $rows = $(".rightDash > table tbody tr").each(function(index) {
          $cells = $(this).find("td.titlePri");
          myRows[index] = {};
          $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
            myRows[index][$($cells[cellIndex]).text()] = $(this).text();
          });
          count++;    
        });
        var myObj = {};
        myObj.myrows = myRows;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj,replacer));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: You can't [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is JSON object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the `tr`s in the body, using the text content of the first `td` in the `tr` as the city name. The third argument to the function provided to `reduce` represents the iteration index:

```js
const cityData = [...document.querySelectorAll('tbody > tr')]
  .reduce((a, tr, i) => {
    a[tr.children[0].textContent] = i + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
console.log(
  { mycities: [
    cityData
  ]}
);
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>city name</th>
      <th>other city info</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Seattle</td>
      <td>Lots of rain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chicago</td>
      <td>Lots of rain</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>Lots of rain</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: exactly what i was trying to accomplish. thanks friend!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this simple script:

```
$('td').each(function(index, obj) {console.log(index, $(this).html())});
```

It returns all what you need and you just need assemble JSON by any way